# Testing an ajax request with Jest causes $ undefined error

Tags: jquery, jestjs

I'm trying to add Jest testing to our existing project. However, we are experiencing some problems. We are trying to to test the following function:

```
// Send picture
function sendESGPIC(results) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "PATH",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(results),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function () {
            // success code
        },
        error: function (data) {
            // error code
        }
    })
}
```

Therefore, we are using the following test that I made.

```
describe("Ajax sendQuestion", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.restoreAllMocks();
    });
    
    var $ = require("jquery");
    var sendQuestion = require(PATH);

    test('sendPicture', async () => {
        const ajaxSpy = jest.spyOn(sendQuestion.sendESGPIC(), 'ajax')

        sendQuestion.sendESGPIC()
    
        expect(ajaxSpy).toBeCalledWith({
            type: "POST",
            url: PATH,
            success: expect.any(Function),
            error: expect.any(Function),
        });
    });
})
```

Unfortunately, we are receiving the following error:
**TypeError: $.ajax is not a function**
This error is caused by our ajax request in the function. We are using the following script tags to import JQuery into our project.

```
  <%- include('../partials/footer') %>
  <script src="/js/basics/ESG_pic.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/questionnaire/esg/sendQuestion.js"></script>
```

The following imports are included into "../partials/footer":

```
  <script src="/js/basics/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/basics/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/basics/xlsx.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/basics/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/basics/mto_basics.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/basics/sidebar.js"></script>
```

To be clear, the JQuery code works perfectly on the page. The only problems we are encountering are during Jest testing.

I guess that our import is not working correctly. However, we have not found a solution yet. Can anybody point is in the right direction how we can properly test the function?

Comment: It's because of the order of js file you added. If your ajax is in /js/basics/ESG_pic.js or /js/questionnaire/esg/sendQuestion.js it must be after jquery

Comment: My appologies. The '../partials/footer' file contains the jquery.min.js import. So, it is imported before the files containing the ajax are imported. I changed the question for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your test is that the `$.ajax` function is not available in the test environment because you are not loading `jQuery` in your Jest test environment. Jest runs in a Node.js environment, and by default, it doesn't have access to the DOM or the jQuery library loaded in the browser.

`jest.spyOn(sendQuestion.sendESGPIC(), 'ajax')` wouldn't work in this case, as far as `sendESGPIC()` actually doesn't have property `ajax`.

You can try to mock the `$.ajax` function in your Jest test.
Like:

```js
jest.mock('jquery');

... 

describe("Ajax sendQuestion", () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
        jest.restoreAllMocks();
    });

  var $ = require("jquery");
  var sendQuestion = require(PATH);

  test('sendPicture success', async () => {
    $.ajax.mockResolvedValue({});

    await sendQuestion.sendESGPIC();

    expect($.ajax).toBeCalledWith({
      type: "POST",
      url: PATH,
      success: expect.any(Function),
      error: expect.any(Function),
    });
  });
});
```